# How to select a date interval in postgresql query?

Tags: postgresql, date

I have query like this:

```
select d.id from days as d JOIN tv_programs AS t ON (d.tv_program_id = t.id) WHERE d.date=? AND t.type=0 ORDER BY d.date, t.date DESC OFFSET 1;
```

it returns data for 1 selected date (type Date), but i want to get values from startDate to endDate, for example, i want to do it using one query which do something like that:

```
select d.id from days as d JOIN tv_programs AS t ON (d.tv_program_id = t.id) WHERE d.date='2011-09-01' AND t.type=0 ORDER BY d.date, t.date DESC OFFSET 1;
select d.id from days as d JOIN tv_programs AS t ON (d.tv_program_id = t.id) WHERE d.date='2011-09-02' AND t.type=0 ORDER BY d.date, t.date DESC OFFSET 1;
select d.id from days as d JOIN tv_programs AS t ON (d.tv_program_id = t.id) WHERE d.date='2011-09-03' AND t.type=0 ORDER BY d.date, t.date DESC OFFSET 1;
```

It's possible?

Comment: yes... what type is `d.date` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`... where d.date between '2011-09-01' and '2011-09-04'` should work.